# App.Config Security in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, security

I am creating a WPF project, and deploying it using ClickOnce. Since the .xbap file is downloaded to the client, and run it from the client machine the client can edit the file and do anyting they wants. That is, if the App.Config file of my WPF appliaction is downloaded along with the .xbap file, and I use some settings to control the behaviour of the application, or use some info like my service detauls, and the user goes to the downloaded location and edits those details they can do anything with it. I have tested this, and this can be done. I have singed my assebmly and manifest with a .pfx certiciate

Since I have signed my assemsbly/manifest, if I perform the same action in the server, the application shows an HashVerification error. Why doesnt this happen in the client side. I think, this is far more important to work in client side then on the server side.

What is the work around to stop users? This could be a serious security issue for many apps. I think this can also be done with Silverlight apps, as it behaves same (not sure if I can paste my modified .xap file to Temporary Internet Folder).

Thanks

Comment: app.config is the domain of the user. You have the wrong expectations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never trust a client.

Whatever you are trying to prevent, expect the user to be an administrator and ready to hack your application.

If you have something to hide (password, connectionstring, ...) do not pass it to the client, keep it on the server.

Comment: The main settings I am putting is actually the service settings, like HTTP throttle info, binding info etc. Also, I have an extra seeting where I put the list of permissible file that can uploaded from the app. Since my UI is only the WPF which connects to a WCF, i cannot put this info in any other config.

Comment: Throttleing is a service side thing. There is not need or use for this info on the client. Or are you hosting the service in the client?

Comment: I am more concerned about the settings of list of files that r permitted to upload. I was putting it in the App.Config of the UI. I didnt wnated to put that validation in WCF, and do an extra hit on the MT

Comment: Put the validation on the server. Do not trust the client. Any process could try to upload anything to the server without even using your client. Server side validation/security is mandatory!

Comment: but, dont u think its generally wrong for users to edit any file/assembly of the .xbap package and still running the app

Comment: Totally agree to the point, that you must never hope, that users will be cute and will not try to make something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

What is the purpose of settings that cannot be changed by the user?

If you want these values to be constant in the deployed code, then I would consider making them constants or resources.

Comment: No....i dont wnat my service URL to be changed by the user. I wnat to change it whenever required and deploy it through ClickOnce. This is similar to web.config in web app. I dont wnat users to change the web.config (not that they can now), but i can app settings like connection strings etc in there. If I wnated something for the user to change, I would have given that in the UI and not in a packeged App.Config file.

Comment: but, settings are deployed in a plain text, seperate file, So that they can be altered by anybody with the appropriate priviliges.

Comment: What about putting the connection string in Web.Config file?